# TM Package: Error in UseMethod("TermDocumentMatrix", x)

Tags: r, tm

I want to plot a term-document matrix like Figure 6 in the [JSS article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuvr2.png) on TM package
 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuvr2.png)The article link: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v025i05

My corpus Speach-English.txt is in here:
https://github.com/yushu-liu/speach-english.git

The figure should look like as follow:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
library(tm)
library(stringr)
library(wordcloud)

text <- paste(readLines("D:/Rdata/speach-English.txt"), collapse = " ")
text_tidy <- gsub(pattern = "\\W",replace=" ",text)
text_tidy2 <- gsub(pattern = "\\d",replace=" ",text_tidy)

text_tidy2 <- tolower(text_tidy2)
text_tidy2 <- removeWords(text_tidy2,stopwords())
text_tidy2 <- gsub(pattern = "\\b[A-z]\\b{1}",replace=" ", text_tidy2 )
text_tidy2 <- stripWhitespace(text_tidy2)

textbag <- str_split(text_tidy2,pattern = "\\s+")
textbag <- unlist(textbag)

tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(textbag, control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE,
                                                removeNumbers = TRUE,
                                                stopwords = TRUE))

plot(tdm, terms = findFreqTerms(tdm, lowfreq = 6)[1:25], corThreshold = 0.5)
```

But one bug came out:

```
Error in UseMethod("TermDocumentMatrix", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'TermDocumentMatrix' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Why? Thanks!

Comment: you are getting this error at the time of running tdm?

Comment: Yes. I google a lot, but still can't find a solution.

Comment: is it possible to put some of text from your file 'speach-English.txt' in the code above?

Comment: Thanks, here is my corpus'Speach-English.txt'

https://github.com/yushu-liu/speach-english.git

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have not created an object of the `Corpus` class, which is the type of object you need to feed to `TermDocumentMatrix()`. See an example of how you could do that below.

Another point I would like to note is that in your line `str_split(text_tidy2,pattern = "\\s+")` you split your text into unigrams (individual terms). Hence, you only get documents of one term each. Creating a tdm from this structure does not make much sense. What is the intended purpose of this line? Maybe I can point you to what you want.

```
library(tm)
text <-  readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yushu-liu/speach-english/master/speach-English.txt")
#first define the type of source you want to use and how it shall be read
x <- VectorSource(text)
#create a corpus object
x <- VCorpus(x)
#feed it to tdm
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(x)
tdm
#<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 4159, documents: 573)>>
#Non-/sparse entries: 14481/2368626
#Sparsity           : 99%
#Maximal term length: 21
#Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

Comment: Error in UseMethod("TermDocumentMatrix", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'TermDocumentMatrix' applied to an object of class "c('TermDocumentMatrix', 'simple_triplet_matrix')"

Comment: What code did you run to get this error, with above code you do not generate a `simple_triple_matrix`. Seems you have fed a document term matrix object to your function. I wil have a further look...

Comment: I have updated my answer and used the text from github you provided. Does that work for you?

Comment: Thanks! It works well. Thanks a lot! And I just found Package 'Rgraphviz' was removed from the CRAN repository. So, it seems impossible to plot that figure.  Plotting this figure need the Package 'Rgraphviz'

Comment: At least your data processing works. You might use the `igraph` package insted to create a network graph or create a `dendogram` via `hclust` to visualize your data. Please also consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I will try it immediately.

Comment: Furthermore, even if the package is not on CRAN anymore (have not checked it), you might still find it on github (maybe a development version) and install the last version from there.